# How do you say ”resolution 1920px*1080px”?

Tags: terminology, pronunciation, technical

How do you say:
”The resolution of this screen is 1920px*1080px"

For example:
"The resolution of this screen is nineteen hundred twenty pixels multiplied by one thousand eighty pixels."

Comment: In general when describing the size of a rectangle I would say "X by Y units", so for a screen, "1920 by 1080 pixels" - no need to repeat the word "pixels" or say "multiplied", indeed with enough context you don't need to say the word "pixels" at all, it's implied. In my experience people usually say resolution numbers the same as years, so "nineteen-twenty by ten-eighty".

Comment: Also, when referring to spatial dimensions, the "multiple" `*` or `×` is always pronounced "by" (as in answers below); it might be used more than once for a 3D object like a storage box.

Comment: There's a fair chance that it'll be described as "ten eighty p".  (This comes from the screen size being the same as the HDTV broadcast standard of "1920x1080 non-interlaced", commonly written as "1080p".)

Comment: @Mark the P actually stands for "Progressive Scan", but technically yes, it is "non-interlaced" too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I agree with @Hot Licks that it should be pronounced "nineteen-twenty by ten-eighty".

No one would ever say "one thousand nine hundred and twenty by one thousand and eighty pixels".